# Jenkin's Nunit plugin not expanding environment variables?

Tags: jenkins, nunit, hudson, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I have a nunit result located at the following location:

```
jobs\Nunit test\Main\nunit-result.xml
```

I specify this location in Nunit plugin field, in Post-build step i.e Publish Nunit-test Result report. This works fine and the builds shows Nunit graph.

The problem that i am getting is when i change the path to:

```
jobs\Nunit test\${branchName}\nunit-result.xml
```

I get the following

```
error: FATAL: No NUnit test report files were found. Configuration error?
```

```
branchName=Main
```

is specified by using EnvInject plugin. This variable is  accessible in HTML publisher plugin where i specify the path of html.

I have searched a lot and i am guessing that the environment variables are not being expanded in the path.

```
Jenkins Version= 1.546, Nunit plugin Version = 0.15
```

Kindly help me in this problem.

Comment: Have you tried this `jobs\Nunit test\$branchName\nunit-result.xml`

Comment: @DipuH
No it didnt help, it is producing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The NUnit plugin doesn't work well with spaces.  Try

```
jobs\Nunit_test\$branchName\nunit-result.xml
```

Comment: Maybe the plugin is using a Windows style Environment Variable.  Try %branchName% instead of $branchName.

Comment: I have tried Windows style Environment Variables. But i get the same error.

Comment: Did you verify the XML file is getting output at the correct location?  Also run an echo command to see if the path is getting output like you expected.  Add an build step for Execute Shell and do "echo $WORKSPACE/jobs/Nunit_test/$branchName/nunit-result.xml" to see the path your job is outputting.

Comment: I have added a build step to echo the path, it is fine.The path is working fine with HTML publisher.But there is some problem with Nunit plugin.
I wasn't able to understand what you meant by "verify the XML file is getting output". Kindly elaborate. Did you mean the config.xml file of the build configuration??

Comment: For example, does "C:\Jenkins\ProjectName\jobs\Nunit_test\ABCBranch\nunit-result.xml" exist?

Comment: Yes, the file exists. When i dont use the $branchName in the path and replace it with "Main", it starts to work fine. The results are uploaded properly. Variable $branchName is working fine throughout the configuration other than nunit plugin. The moment i add $branchName to the path,the configuration fails.

Comment: How are you calling your nunit console?  Using "Execute Shell" or using "Windows batch command?"  The nunit console will also need quotes.  For example:  nunit-console.exe "$WORKSPACE\jobs\Nunit test\$branchName\UnitTests.nunit" /xml="$WORKSPACE\jobs\Nunit test\$branchName\nunit-result.xml"  if you're using Shell.  It will need to be %WORKSPACE% and %branchName% when using Windows batch command.

Comment: I am calling nunit console using Windows batch command. I am using %WORKSPACE% and %branchName% with quotes. The file is generated at the specified location. but when i try to access it using environment variable there is an error. The same path works fine with HTML publisher.I will try upgrading Jenkins to latest version and try again. May be that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins NUnit plugin only allows to specify XML file paths in "Ant glob syntax". Hence, when you echo your path containing an environment variable, you are able to see it recognizing the environment variable properly, while NUnit plugin does not interpret it the same way.